# CMake response file format issue with Ninja generator

Tags: cmake, linker, ninja

I am currently using CMake (3.7.1) to generate Ninja build files for linking many static libraries.

I can see in the Ninja rules that response files are being used to shorten the command line:

```
rspfile = $RSP_FILE
rspfile_content = $in_newline $LINK_PATH $LINK_LIBRARIES
```

The generated response file contains a single line of paths to the libraries, as expected.

My problem is that the linker driver insists that option files must only contain one linker option per line.

I haven't yet found a way to disable RSP files for the Ninja generator.

I also tried to produce the correct format by adding an '\n' character after each library path, but this resulted in a CMake error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually if I look at [`cmNinjaNormalTargetGenerator.cxx`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmNinjaNormalTargetGenerator.cxx#L207) CMake/Ninja should generate the response files with newlines with the exception of "GCC on Windows". What platform and which compilers do you use?

Comment: @Florian I'm using Windows with a Greenhills C compiler, and definitely no newlines.  Even object files contained in _$in_newline_ variable.  Anyway, it turns out that the static library includes don't count as 'linker options' and can be passed to the Compiler control program using the standard _@filename_ syntax.